# How to add code to HTTP header

Tags: http-api

I have a code that I need to insert into the HTTP header of my website to make Google Fonts work again.

My Google Fonts aren't rendering on one of my simple websites (http://ceobusinessalliance.com). I coded it from scratch using Bootstrap and WordPress. They were rendering before but are no longer. According to the error in the console and Google's support page (https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/troubleshooting), I need to make sure `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` is in the header.

What is the function I use to do this? I'm not a very strong WordPress developer. I mostly work with developing themes.

Edit: I am using Chrome.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the dev console, and the font files are loaded properly for me, although as you said, they aren't showing up on the site.  Did anything else change?  Did you upgrade anything?

Comment: I haven't upgraded anything lately. Usually, I update once a month and check to make sure everything is working. I suspect it might be something with Google? Or an update with my browser (Chrome)?

Comment: Your page renders fine for me in Chrome (Roboto Slab and PT Sans fonts), not getting console error either.

Comment: You're right. It's showing up for me, too. Everywhere but the h3 tags on the homepage! Please see the screenshot here: http://i61.tinypic.com/2mdjdxz.png . I know this is beyond help about WordPress, but I really appreciate your guyses help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has the action `send_headers`, which you can use to make it send additional headers:

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'add_header_acao' );
function add_header_acao() {
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
}
```

See the documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/send_headers

Comment: Thanks, JHoffmann. It doesn't seem to have solved my Google Fonts issue. Is there any way I can test to see if the browser read the command? (I looked through inspect element and couldn't find anything).

Comment: First off: For me the fonts are rendering (in FireFox), at least for example the nav menu is in Roboto Slab as it should be.

Comment: For me as well. Body is PT Sans.

Comment: You can see if the header arrived at the client if you use tools like the network monitor in FireFox. And there too I can see the header on your site.

Comment: Yes, I too can see it in Firefox. The issue is in Chrome. I neglected to add that to the question. I will add that information now.

Comment: Commenting here as I can't comment on the main question yet:
By the error message on your screenshot I can see the real problem is not the header being missing on your site, but on fonts.gstatic.com. But at least for me they send it in the response. So maybe there is some proxy on your connection filtering the header out or something similar.